# Log of access to synology ds213+

Tags: router, nas, synology

I do have the following configuration:

- dlink dir-615 router
- nas synology ds213+ (DSM 4.2)
- dynamic dns (through dlinkddns.com)

All the data are for personal (family) purpose only, however I would like to access something through internet (PhotoStation, FileStation). This works well, but I get a lot of requests from search engines and probably from some hacking activities. This is not a big security issue, but it wakes-up NAS from hibernation twice every hour.

I thought I can turn-on inbound filter on my router, unfortunately I am not able to find any logs on what IP accessed my NAS.

My question are:

- where is detailed traffic log on Synology?
- is inbound filter (deny specific IP addresses) good strategy or there is better one?

Comment: Denying specific IP address is a bad idea as you will ends up putting the rest of internet into that list. Your better bet is to do whitelisting. If you know what IP range your ISP / mobile phone provider uses, you can whitelist those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question:

**Where is detailed traffic log on Synology?**

1. On the top left menu bar, open the menu pane.
2. Click on **System Logs**
3. In the new window, click on the **Connection** tab.
4. Here you'll find a list of users and their connected IP Addresses.

Alternatively you can set up a **Syslog Server** which will help you trap all kind of system events, whether it's I/O operations or Network traffic. You can download the syslog package from the **Package Center** then go into your **Control Panel** and point the syslog client server to `localhost`.

[image: Step 1 - Click on the menu on the top left corner]
[image: Step 3 - IP addresses]

**Is inbound filter (deny specific IP addresses) good strategy or there is better one?**

You can control IP address access through the firewall menu.

1. On the top left menu bar, open the menu pane.
2. Click on **Control Panel**
3. Click on the **Firewall and QoS** icon.
4. Set Allow/Deny rules.

If you want to tightly lock down your NAS, you can set ALLOW to a list of IP addresses that you trust and then create a DENY rule to deny from ALL.

Now you need to make sure the ALLOW IP addresses are not ISP provided/ dynamic IPs. If those IP were to change, you will be locked out from your device forever.

[image: Firewall rules]

In my opinion, if you are accessing these files through the internet. It would be more secure to set up a **VPN server** and block all data access except to local IPs only. Most modern OS comes equipped with VPN modules that makes set up a breeze. Such as Win 7 and OS X.